# In JProfiler how to expand the number of biggest objects?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, profiling, jprofiler

I'm trying to use JProfiler to find biggest objects in my App.
It shows me top 6 biggest objects, and cuts off everything else. I can't figure out how to see more top objects. Probably missing something obvious. Or maybe it's a problem on MacOS?
Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: Jmeter biggest objects profiling]

You can see there are other 2,884,610 objects that consume 249MB memory. How can I see more of them?
In the legend I found the following help message:

> "In order to keep the UI responsive, JProfiler only shows a small
>   number of top-level objects.
>
> Clicking on the hyperlink in the node will add more top-level objects.
>   The block size of the number of added instances can be confiured in
>   the view settings."

But I can't find the hyperlink in the node. Can someone point me to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Click --> Use selected Instances --> Biggest Objects